# View has different position on iphone 4 and 5/6 without Auto-layout

Tags: ios, view

I am not using auto-layout but I have a view on storyboard (using the interface builder) which on the view attributes has this :

```
X : 0 , Y : 43, Width :325, Height : 362.
```

I am not using auto-layout and the view on the IB has a fixed simulated size.

On iphone 4 - the view's dimension become  :

```
ContainerView. X : 0.000000 Y:63.000000 Height :362.000000 Width : 325.000000
```

On iphone 5/6 they become :

```
ContainerView. X : 0.000000 Y:151.000000 Height :362.000000 Width : 325.000000
```

So, Y is different.

ViewController does not use navigation bars or anything else.

1. Why on iphone 4 they are different than the one's on IB?
2. Why that difference between 4 and 5/6? I guess because of the different screen size and the difference in status bar - but that difference is not 88 pt, isn't it?
3. What's the best way to have it on the same position ? Programmatically check the device and adjust the frame or use auto-layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable AutoLayout this means you are using Autoresizing which has limited feature of adapting your view to size and orientation changes. Check your Autoresizing masks

[image]

Recommended way to use AutoLayout with size classes so you can fine tune all the UI components according to different size and orientation. You may take a look official Apple documentation for reference

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

[image]

[image]